# Is there any demo of using javascript / typescript to interact with solana program

Tags: program, javascript, typescript

Is there any demo of using javascript / typescript to interact with solana program ?

For example, how to interact with this program ?
https://solscan.io/account/MSPCUMbLfy2MeT6geLMMzrUkv1Tx88XRApaVRdyxTuu

Answer (score 2):

In order to interact with a random program you would need to know more about the instruction and state interfaces. Some programs will have public IDLs or the programs themselves will be open source, check the website of the project you want to call into. Once you have that, check out Anchor repo for an example integration using the Anchor framework for interacting with programs in Typescript: https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/tree/master/examples/tutorial